# Can i transmit (to lotus notes) custom items in ical format

Tags: lotus-notes, icalendar

we have a customized maildb, the appointment form has custom (CRM) items. As far as I see, I cannot fill/update these items by the new notes (9.x) ical classes? 
As a workaround I update these fields after "icalling", via the backend document, but (of course) invited people only get the original ical infos, not the custom items. 
Any way to fill in the custom items BEFORE the invitations will go out?

Thanks for any help, 
Uwe